# Setting a date variable in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Why does the following return a `MEDIUMTEXT` type?

```
set @entered_date = date "2015-01-01";
select @entered_date;
```

What would be the correct way to store a date in mysql and then later reference that?

Comment: How do you know it is a `MEDIUMTEXT`?

Comment: @GMB it says in the field types metadata.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be using single quotes for MySQL date literals:

```sql
set @entered_date = '2015-01-01';
```

Double quotes indicate database objects.  Note that you don't need the ANSI `date` keyword here.